# LibreOffice OnLine build

Tags: compilation, gtk, libreoffice, gdk

I'm trying to compile libreoffice, to use it "online", i.e: in a web browser (see a demo here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CVR7HqDokmA
).

When running the executable, I get this error:

```
**Gdk-ERROR **: Unsupported GDK backend: broadway**
```

These are the steps I do to compile libreoffice on a Ubuntu 11.10 Linux box:

```
cd /opt
mkdir -p libreoffice
cd libreoffice/

git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/core
cd core

cat >> /etc/apt/sources.list << EOT

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu oneiric main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/libreoffice/ppa/ubuntu oneiric main
EOT

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 1378B444
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get build-dep libreoffice

sudo apt-get install -y libgnomevfs2-dev
sudo apt-get install -y doxygen

./autogen.sh --enable-gtk3 --without-java --disable-mozilla --without-system-mozilla
make

make dev-install

cd install/program;
. ./ooenv;
export SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN=gtk3
export GDK_BACKEND=broadway
./soffice --writer
```

---

What is the problem here? Is there any other compilation option I can check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems your GTK hasn't been compiled with the broadway backend enabled. Depends on your distro.

Comment: Thanks. Now it's clearer... I suppose I'll try the build process on a new (virtual) box, since I would risk to smash up my system, rebuilding the gtk with custom flags... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As liberforce correctly pointed out, you need a BROADWAY-enabled GTK.
I did just discover ubuntu 12.04 ships with a BROADWAY-enabled GTK...